# Use LED as a latching diode

Tags: led, diodes, logic-gates

I am working with 74HC08 (AND gate chip). I have to assemble my circuit according to following image:

[image]

Everything works fine, but I have suddenly a fancy idea to replace 1N4148 diodes with low-power LEDs. Like this, I could visualize the latching effect. However, my LEDs don't emit any light. The circuit behaves without any abberration if the lowest diode is substituted by LED (no light, as I mentioned). I was thinking that probably the voltage on the lowest gate is too low, so I put the LED on the first (the upper one) gate. No light neither, moreover, the overall output perturbed the function of the rest of my circuit (which is below the lowest gate).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LED drops too much voltage. For it to work reliably you need the input voltage to exceed Vih which means about 3.5V with a 5V supply, meaning there is only about 1.5V for the LED, and the output will not be exactly at Vcc either since it's sourcing some current.

It might work more-or-less unreliably (very little noise margin and when warm) if you use red color LEDs (the lowest drop of visible LEDs) - the typical Vih at room temperature is about 2.67V leaving about 2.3V for the LED. Some red LEDs have typical 1.75V or so at room temperature.

Comment: He could also try operating at 6 volts, since 74HC is rated for that.

Comment: Isn't there a point on the diode curve which would allow, say, 1 volt drop on LED while still making it light up? Of course it depends on actual diodes used which we know nothing about.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, no , I can't, because I'm using voltage regulator.

Comment: What is "red" LED? Red colored plastic? Actually I'm perplexed with the definition "low-voltage LED". Shop owner doesn't provide any information neither. How can I find out which LED is "low-voltage" and which one is "normal" one?

Comment: The forward voltage at a given current is generally less for LEDs that emit longer wavelength light. So Vf for a red-emitting LED is typically less than that of a green, yellow or blue LED. White LEDs usually behave electrically like blue.

Comment: You should try to get only parts with proper data sheets.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, I don't think your suggestion will work because increasing VCC to 6 VDC also increases VIH to about 4.2 VDC (according to the data sheet I'm looking at). So the situation Sphero describes still exists--i.e., if the AND gate's output current is 10 mA, to get decent light intensity out of the LED, the AND gate's output voltage will drop to around 5.5 V, and subtracting ~1.8 VDC for the LED's forward voltage drop leaves 3.7 VDC at the AND gate's input pin, which is below the AND gate's VIH spec of 4.2 VDC, and therefore there's no guarantee the AND gate will latch.

Comment: @JimFischer - I never said it was guaranteed. However, the point is that since the diode ON voltage will be pretty much constant, the resistor (and therefor the input) voltage will climb more than the threshold voltage, which will be roughly proportional to Vcc. Consider what would happen if the gates were replaced by CD4000 series, and the supply voltage increased to 12 volts.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Spehro's answer] - your pull downs are too large for those LEDs too light up. If you only replaced the diodes leaving the resistors as shown the current through those LEDs is on the order of tens of microamps, far too low.

Make sure to use red LEDs and lower those resistors to 1k or even 470 Ohms.

Comment: Should I remove resistors or reduce their resistance?

Comment: @tenghiz lower, to 1k Ohms to begin with.

Comment: I checked a few datasheets, and HC gate outputs are characterized up to only 4 mA of sourcing current.  With this, plus the Vf of the LED, you can calculate the minimum resistor value.

Comment: @AnalogKid good catch with those 4 mA (reading datasheet is a pain on mobile). A red LED usually has around 1.2-1.5 Vf at ten or so mA so using a 1k resistor here is a good starting point. Also please notice that we do not know anything about what kind of LEDs are used.

Comment: I have measured an amperage on the upper gate, indeed, it is 4 mA. The lowest one behaves quite strange: when I insert multimeter between diode and gate output, there is no latching effect. I must continuously press the button in order to let the current go. So far, I am still very uncomfortable with datasheets and don't know which information is relevant to my question. As for resistors, I followed your advise and tried both 1kOhm and 470 Ohm values. Unfortunately, it's not enough to light a LED.